# Problems recording on device using serial port

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port

I need to connect to a sensor through a serial port and read some data off it. I can connect to it fine, but when I send the command, nothing is sent and returned from the device. The parameters I used to initialize and the command I send are the same I use in Putty.

```
private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort RS232 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(); 
RS232 = new SerialPort("COM4", 900, Parity.Mark, 8, StopBits.Two);
RS232.RtsEnable = true;
RS232.DtrEnable = true;
RS232.Handshake = Handshake.None;
RS232.Write("set localip 166.166.3.333\r\n");
```

When I write "set localip XXXXX" in Putty , that IP address is recorded in the plate, but nothing happend when I use it in .NET

Any ideas?

Comment: do you use the `\r\n` in putty?

Comment: No.. in Putty i use set localip 166.166.3.333 and press ENTER... But it test using RS232.Write("set localip 166.166.3.333"); and it doesn´t work either.

Comment: Have you double checked your serial port setting in your program with those in putty?

Comment: i use the configuration i mentioned bebore 
RS232 = new SerialPort("COM4", 900, Parity.Mark, 8, StopBits.Two);
is the same i use in Putty. It has Access to the port COM4, when Putty is active, my App says the port is busy...How can I double check it?.  thanks..

Comment: What does the sensor expect for an `end of command` character?  You can set this as the `RS232.NewLine` property, then use `RS232.WriteLine` to write a command that should be executed.  This could be a `end of transmission` character, or ASCII 4, for example.  Or just try using the default `WriteLine` before making any changes.

Comment: Also, have you attached event handlers to the following events? `ErrorReceived`, `DataReceived`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I didnot thought errorReceived... i just try and  give an error type "RXParity".      but i am using Parity.Mark, the same config as Putty.

Comment: I put Parity.None.. the error desappear but it doesn´t work anyway. thanks

Comment: It expect an Enter as end of command... that is why I use WriteLine.. I put WriteLine() before any changes but it doesn´t work.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the port before send information, so need to use the Open method:

```
RS232.Open();//If not exception, now you can send data
RS232.Write("set localip 166.166.3.333\r\n");
```